# Why do the d3 time range functions normalize values when using step?

Tags: time, d3.js

Why does the following range function...

```
d3.time.minute.range(
    new Date('Sat Aug 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400'),
    new Date('Sat Aug 17 2013 06:00:00 GMT-0400'),
    22);
```

...return an array like this...

```
[
Sat Aug 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 00:22:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 00:44:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), // << normalized to 1am
Sat Aug 17 2013 01:22:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 01:44:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 02:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), // << normalized to 2am
...
]
```

...instead of like this?

```
[
Sat Aug 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 00:22:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 00:44:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 01:06:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 01:28:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 01:50:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
Sat Aug 17 2013 02:12:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
...
]
```

I'm trying to render a timeline and then use `d3.time.scale` to correlate pixels and time.  Each `rect` I render is meant to represent 22 minutes in this example.  When I bind `.data()` to the result of this range function, my `text` elements don't clearly represent actual time in all cases.

What sort of problems am I going to run into if I avoid using `d3.time.minute.range` and simply add 22 minutes (`.getTime() + 22 * 60 * 1000`) myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what mbostock said here, I think you need to roll your own:
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/d3-js/1344en8cz8/time-scale-always-forcibly-display-first-date-of-a-month

So:

```
d3.time.minute.range(
    new Date('Sat Aug 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400'),
    new Date('Sat Aug 17 2013 06:00:00 GMT-0400'))
.filter(function(d) {
    return (d - new Date('Sat Aug 17 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400')) % (22 * 60 * 1000) == 0;
});
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JHTQf/

As far as problems, I think either will be fine since browsers don't have leap seconds.  I'd take into account DST but I think that is fixed with UTC calculations.